# Examples of unsoundness of conditional types

Tags: typescript

I was reading [a paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3498698) that, speaking about conditional types, states:

> The unsoundness is caused by the incorrect widening of type parameters in contravariant position. [...] The conditional type unification algorithm
> wrongly approximates `X => string` to `any => string` and unifies the former with latter, which can
> lead to a runtime errors.

I have not precisely understood what they meant. When does the unification algorithm unifies `X => string` with `any => string`? An example would be really appreciated.

Something like the following seems to behave correctly, even the other way around:

```
type Test<X> = ((x:X) => string) extends ((x:number) => string) ? true : false
```

Comment: I'd think the onus should be on the authors of the paper to provide an example; TS is certainly both unsound and incomplete, so I could probably come up with an example of unsoundness involving a conditional type, but it's not clear it would be what they meant or what you're looking for.

Comment: @jcalz Yes you are right, but they haven't provided anything related to what they are saying so I wondered if anyone would be able to understand it better than me. Yes ofc conditionals are unsound, there are some interesting open issues, but I've never heard about problems of the unification algorithm with type parameters in contravariant positions

Comment: Oh well, I haven't found anything obvious in playing around with generic function types in conditional types, nor have I found anything in GitHub that is definitely relevant.  Guess I'll just shrug and move on.  ‍♂️ ‍♂️